# How to enable manipulation events in custom control?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

I am creating a Windows Phone 7.5 Silverlight application. 
I am creating a new custom control:

```
public class ChartCanvas : Canvas
```

When I use it on another page, it doesn't fire any events. Here is my XAML:

```
<Controls:ChartCanvas x:Name="chartControl" 
                      Margin="8"
                      DoubleTap="chartControl_DoubleTap" 
                      ManipulationStarted="chartControl_ManipulationStarted" />
```

How do I enable the `DoubleTap` event and manipulation events for this control?

Answer (score 0):

You probably would want to bind your events to your datacontext's ViewModel since this would have a control that is generic that can have different implementation of handling the events.

Unless you explicitly coded in the ChartCanvas behind the code the logic for DoubleTap/ManipulationStarted and don't want it to be generic e.g. for handling data/stuff then this should be fine

Comment: Yes, sure, this is just an example. But my question is a bit another.

Comment: I thought your question was how to enable the DoubleTap event and manipulation events for the control?

Comment: Yes the question is the on you mentioned. The problem is that these events doesn't fire at all. I added event handlers and put there breakpoints and breakpoints doesn't fire.

Comment: Where is your breakpoint, could you give more sample code? Which class is it?