# Enable Manipulation On Windows Phone 8

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8

I have the following code which I found from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12648318/handle-swipe-up-swipe-down-swipe-left-swipe-right-gestures-in-a-winrt-app):

```
private void Grid_ManipulationStarted_1(object sender, ManipulationStartedRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        initialpoint = e.Position;
    }

    private void Grid_ManipulationDelta_1(object sender, ManipulationDeltaRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.IsInertial)
        {
            Point currentpoint = e.Position;
            if (currentpoint.X - initialpoint.X >= 500)//500 is the threshold value, where you want to trigger the swipe right event
            {
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Swipe Right");
                e.Complete();
            }
        }
    }
```

And my Xaml:

```
<Page
x:Class="MyApp.DetailPage"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:local="using:MyApp"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
mc:Ignorable="d">
<Viewbox x:Name="MainViewbox" Stretch="Uniform" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="1, 1, 1, 1" ManipulationDelta="Grid_ManipulationDelta_1" ManipulationStarted="Grid_ManipulationStarted_1">
    <Grid ManipulationDelta="Grid_ManipulationDelta_1" ManipulationStarted="Grid_ManipulationStarted_1" Background='Transparent'>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <TextBlock x:Name="IDAndTitleTxt" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Top" Grid.Row="1" TextAlignment="Center" Height="Auto" Width="Auto" FontSize="20" Foreground="White"/>
        <TextBlock x:Name="IssueType" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Top" Text="Code Defect" MaxHeight="10" Height="Auto" Width="Auto" Foreground="White" FontSize="4"/>
        <TextBlock x:Name="UserAssignedTo" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="Auto" Width="Auto" Grid.Row="3" Foreground="White" FontSize="8"/>
        <TextBlock x:Name="StateSubstate" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Top" Text="Active / In Progress" Height="Auto" Width="Auto" Grid.Row="4" Foreground="White" FontSize="8"/>
        <Button x:Name="BackBtn" Content="Back" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="40" Width="40" Grid.RowSpan="2" Grid.Row="0"/>
        <ScrollViewer Height="260" Width="200" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" Grid.Row="2" Canvas.Top="60" Canvas.Left="340">
            <TextBlock Width="195" TextWrapping="Wrap" FontSize="5" x:Name="DescriptionTxt"/>
        </ScrollViewer>
   </Grid>
</Viewbox>
```

My problem is that both the manipulation events never fire no matter how much I swipe the screen in all directions. I've put breakpoints on the event handlers to confirm this. Someone else has already asked the same question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12129616/how-to-enable-manipulation-events-in-custom-control) but there is no answers. Seeing as that question was more than 2 years ago, I'm rewriting it.

Also, my grid is inside a viewbox, which is in a page (not a window).

Any help is appreciated :).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you meant a Windows Phone 8.1 runtime application? Because in silverlight it works fine. 
For that you should set `ManipulationMode` to `All` for your grid. In my test it worked fine even without a background color (which is necessary in silverlight applications).

If you need just a subset of manipulations, you should use the best mode for your needs.

Comment: Thanks very much... This worked perfectly first time :).

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a background brush - eg `Background="Transparent"` - in order for it to receive input events.

Comment: I tried that but still nothing... I've posted my full Xaml just in case that would help.